# hibernate AnnotationConfiguration is deprecated... but using Configuration results in MappingException

Tags: hibernate, configuration, annotations

Here is my code:

```
        Configuration config = new Configuration().configure();
```

which gives :

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="com.google.musicstore.domain.Record"/>
```

fine... so I try to use org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration instead :

```
        Configuration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
```

but that class is deprecated.  The docs instruct me to use Configuration instead!

As a side note, the AnnotationConfiguration option fails also, resulting in :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

Here is my pom.xml :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Help please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had two different versions of hibernate lying around in my classpath.  Once I resolved this and just used 4.3.0.Final, everything was fine.  Silly me!

Answer (score 1):

Use `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration`, as you first tried, but replace the entry in pom.xml with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```