# Hibernate: object.org.hibernate.MappingException

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is the exception i am facing, it occurs when i call session.save

```
object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:
  com.java.learn.pojo.Employee
```

here is my java code

```
try
{
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder =
        new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    SessionFactory factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Employee e = new Employee(1, "", "", 3);
    e.setFirstName("sparsh");
    session.save(e);
    System.out.println("in dao");
}
catch (Throwable ex)
{
    System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
    factory.close();
    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
}
```

and here is my `hibrnate.cfg.xml`

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">
            org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
            com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        </property>

        <!-- Assume students is the database name -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
            jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
            root
        </property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
            root1
        </property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.java.learn.pojo.Employee"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

this exception occurs because of no mapping for Pojo class, but I have added it.

Pojo class

```
package com.java.learn.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Table
@Entity
public class Employee
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private int salary;

    public Employee()
    {
    }

    public Employee(int id, String firstName, String lastName, int salary)
    {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName()
    {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String first_name)
    {
        this.firstName = first_name;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String last_name)
    {
        this.lastName = last_name;
    }

    public int getSalary()
    {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary)
    {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: where have you placed your `hibrnate.cfg.xml`?

Comment: in web-inf/classes

Comment: I think this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4001795/org-hibernate-mappingexception-unknown-entity) will help you.

Comment: @sparsh610 you should place it in your resources folder. Or if it's any other folder, then you should give that path in configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Configuration().configure()` to load the Entity mappings from `hbm.xml` files.

But because you are using **annotations for your `Employee` Entity class**, you simply need to use `AnnotationConfiguration` instead of `Configuration` as shown below:

So, **replace the line below**:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
```

**with**:

```
 Configuration configuration = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure();
```

Comment: but annoationconfiguration get deprectaed ... also u trying to inject sessionfactory in configuration instance

Comment: You can look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19611383/hibernate-annotationconfiguration-is-deprecated-but-using-configuration-resul

Comment: Also, I suggest first try with `AnnotationConfiguration` and check if it works and then can drill down what could be the issue...

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

The problem is obvious here, you have not correctly mapped your `Employee` entity which is so relevant from the error stack trace:

> object.org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.java.learn.pojo.Employee

And the problem is that the mapped entity in your `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file can't be reached because you placed your file under `web-inf/classes` so when `hibernate` tries to look for your Entity it will look for it under `web-inf/classes` and it won't find it.

**Solution:**

To solve this problem you just need to place your `hibernate.cfg.xml` file under `Java/src` folder instead of `web-inf/classes` so the Entity can be reached.